# MAMP 6.7 won't start on port 80

Tags: apache, mamp, startup, port80

I  just upgraded to MAMP version 6.7, to get php 8,  it won't start  on port 80 from GUI but it starts from command line with /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start (no error messages). Previous version of MAMP (5.7) was running without any problems).

I do not have any other applikation running on port 80 (did: ps aux | grep httpd  ).
I do not get any error message in MAMPs error log.

I can start MAMP Apache server on any other port.

I had deactivated Macs own Apaoche server with:
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null

Installed new version off MAMP, copied over config files for mysql to bin (as I have password for mysql server), configurated phpMyAdmin for http login and no password, chosed php 8.20 in GUI for starting MAMP, checked that port 80 for Apache and 3306 from mysql was configurated, started server.

Edit: It was something about the admin rights on the log files in MAMP/logs (was set to: root as user and admin as group), so I changed permission on apache_error file. to my username (as I i have apache running under it) and read write for group admin, still server do not start.

It is something about the password prompt for the main GUI that not get trigged, I actually want to have that prompt when I start the MAMP servers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some problem here. (coldstarting) MAMP 6.7  should start normally at port 80, even more so when you've just changed versions from 6.3 to 6.7, where 6.3 was running on port 80 without any problems. The MySQL server does start so I've compared the httpd.conf of 6.3 with the 6.7 version and there are only a few changes made, most noticeably the addition of phpMyAdmin5.

Comment: I upgraded from 5.7 (was main release). No problem with mysql  server, it starts. Apache also starts from command line, even without password, witch I do not like. I had prompt for starting MAMP before, it will not even prompt.
The funny thing is that Google drive disconnect every time I start Apache.
I have tested a lot of different things, like copy over old httpd.conf (then I had to disable some modules in files). I tested changing group on both MAMP installation and the website (to both admin and staff).

Comment: The permission prompt happens when you try to start listening on port 80 or 443.

This suggests that Google Drive is competing for the same ports MAMP uses. Before starting MAMP, open a terminal (Mac)

sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :$PORT

You should see Google in that list and what port it is using. Do the same when you start MAMP (and Google disconnects) and check what port MAMP is using to see if they overlap.

I just reverted my version from 6.7 back to 6.3 where all works fine, it ships with an early version of PHP8.0.8 so I will try to get the newest PHP8 to work there.

Comment: I did  sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep 80, and there is nothing running on it. Only in short sequence when I have to log in to google drive again (by web-browser), there is a process a short time. When I close the login site, it goes away. 

When I star Apache from the command prompt I get seven connections, like this:

httpd      9521           klas    4u  IPv6 0x3fdcb9825c25ec3b      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

Why so many process and why IPV6? Is it one for every virtual host? I had disabled Ipv6 for my network for my Mac. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the 6.8 version.
Each time I start MAMP on port 80, I got an error :
"Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration."

So my solution is, each time I start MAMP, to open a Terminal and do :

```
sudo apachectl start
```

MAMP gets green and starts ...
that is, for the moment, the only way for me to use port 80

Answer (score -1):

I upgrade to new version 6.8 of MAMP now who just come out, and that solved the problem, Apache starts and i get the prompt for password when using port 80.

The upgrade process is quite stupid though, IT DID NOT TAKE BACKUP on config files and database, when it wrote the date named backup files for old installation in Applications. Gladly I have strong routine on backup both by hand and in  my system setup. So had to copy over config files for mySql (in bin directory) and database directory(in db directory). Need to do this on every new installation of MAMP.
This is stupid MAMP, fix it!